# Get all applications for found application pools using appcmd

Tags: powershell, iis, appcmd

I want to get a list of all `applications` (`vdirs` or `physical paths` are also fine) that are running under an `application pool` with a specific `userName`.

What I already tried is the following:

```
appcmd.exe list apppool /processModel.userName:{USERNAME} /xml | appcmd.exe list app /in
```

I first retrieve a list of `applicaion pools` that are configured with a specific `userName`. Then using piping, I retrieve the `applications` based on the `application pools` I got in the former command. Is this correct what I'm doing here? Because in the latter command I put `/in` after `app`, which looks wrong...

Comment: Does your first command execute correctly?

Comment: @JennyDai, yes. Everything looks working correctly. I just wanted to double check if this is the correct way.

Comment: It looks like this is right, try to run the commands separately, execute the next command with the application pool obtained from the previous command.